# Cmder as desktop background

Tags: conemu, cmder

Is it possible to make cmder as desktop background in Windows 10 with which I could interact?

e.g. In Ubuntu we can set terminal as desktop background https://askubuntu.com/questions/366599/use-a-terminal-as-desktop-background-instead-of-the-wallpaper